# How to achieve automatic backups of installed packages before updating them?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, packages

I am looking for a way (configuration or program) to automatically backup currently installed package before its update is done. I mean whole package, not just a version number.

I found some applications which can backup installed packages, like Aptik, but they are not automatic. They have to be manually run every time.

Comment: Are the updates automatic or manual? Perhaps we can figure a workaround, if not else.

Comment: Updates are manual - I am using aptitude. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll try to find out if it has some hooks or something similar.

Comment: At the very least, you could invoke a simple bash script. :) But there should be more elegant ways.